# Inherit members from multiple class

Tags: c#, oop

I've been learning to design with OOD and stuck with a scenario.

I have a class `User` which extends an abstract class `Person`. Class `Person` has a member with type `Address`. `User` only have Username and Password, and `Address` have some string fields.

Now, I want to add a class `Client` which can be a `Person` or an `Organization`(to be added). `Client` will have some data also.

I thought about interfaces but they can have only methods. Can anyone help me with what will be the proper design?

I'm not following any pattern and coding with C#.NET.

---

### Update

I think I could not explain the scenario properly. Sorry for that. Please, have a look on the diagram. Here, the `Client` class is what I want to add.
[image: Incomplete class diagram of my scenario]

Comment: "I thought about interfaces but they can have only methods." No, they can have properties and events too... It's not entirely clear to me what you're trying to model though...

Comment: Does client need to be an user? If So Client must inherit from User,  move address to user and so it will have now address too.

Maybe you should add must override readonly property "UserType" to User class which is overridden in sub classes. Sub classes defines what kind of UserTypes they are.

Comment: Interfaces are not limited to methods, they can have properties getter setter and events too. i'd prefer interfaces here

Comment: Also, I guess `Organization`s also have an `Address`. So maybe `Address` should be on `Client` and `Person` and `Organization` should derive from `Client`?

Comment: From your question I cannot pick a class which should be inherited from multiple classes

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy It's the `Client` class which may be inherited from `Person` or `Organization`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to work with composition. A person and an organization are not necessarily a user, although they both can HAVE an address or a user account. Actually they most likely have more than one of both.
If you think more in terms of HAS A and less in terms of IS A you can come up with more maintainable choices.
For instance you can have a

```
class Address {
  public string street {get; private set;}
  public string city {get; private set;}
  public AddressTypes AddressType {get; private set;} // an enum to differentiate 
                                                      // "home address", "legal address"
  ...
}
```

now, if you need to model the fact that both a `Person` and a `Organization` are things that must have `Address`es, you can create an interface

```
interface IAddressable {
   IEnumerable<Address> {get;}
}
```

and have both `Person` and `Organization` implement it. The same can be done with an `Account` class that holds `Username` and `Password`.

Now `Person` and `Organization` don't need to BE `User`s, but they can both HAVE Accounts, Addresses and anything else you need. And you can force them to have these things via interfaces, as shown above.

As for `Client`, I can see your problem. You are tempted to say that "a Person (or an Organization) IS a Client". But in your design "a Person IS already a User" and you can't have Person inherit from two different base classes.

However, note that a Person is not necessarily a client. I'm not sure what a Client exactly is in your model, but let's assume it's someone with an Address and an Account who can be a Person or an Organization (and you want to know if it's one or the other).
You can do this in several ways, but one could be:

```
abstract class Client : IAddressable, IWithAccount {
   // implement IAddressable and IWithAccount
}

class PersonClient : Client
{
    public PersonClient(Person person)
    {
        // make the Client's address refer to the Person's address
        // make the Client's account refer to the Person's account
    }
}

class OrganizationClient : Client
{
    public OrganizationClient(Organization organization)
    {
        // make the Client's address refer to the Organization's address
        // make the Client's account refer to the Organization's account
    }
}
```

the advantages are that:

- you don't have to change your existing code to retro-fit a role (Client) as a base class of existing entities (Person, Organization).
- if your company starts having for instance States as Clients, you can add a `StateClient` without changing the existing pieces

Comment: Thanks for a good advise. I added the `User` class only for the users of the system. They don't need to be a `Person`. But they can have personal details.

Comment: `Person` is an abstract class. How can I instantiate that?

Comment: @Raihan I'm not sure I understand your question, but you will need a concrete class inheriting from Person if it's an abstract class.

Comment: When I want to get all the clients, there's a problem with your design. I have to call `PersonClient.GetAll()` and `OrganizationClient.GetAll()`.

Comment: @Raihan my code was just an example. You can make Client a non abstract class if you need it that way. And if the types of clients are not going to be extended in the future you can have an enum in Client that specifies the type of client, like I did for AddressType in the Address class, instead of PersonClient and OrganizationClient subclasses